# How to refine this logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to refine this logo in Photoshop using basic tools like the rubber and smudge tools.

I want to know if there is an easier, faster way to refine the logo - to remove some of the depth - and change it from 'grainy' to 'all one depth' - if that makes sense?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Valentina and welcome to GDSE. The question is interesting technically but I would strongly advice you ensure that you are legally allowed to use this bas-relief/sculpture as a logo in the first place. Have you already made sure of that?

Comment: Hi Emilie! I believe the image is in the public domain so no permission is required to use it. I might be wrong, but that is all I know. Valentina

Comment: @Valentina even if it is you get into problems since you are now asserting that the image is yours which makes it hard to defend the logo legally.

Comment: You could use a [similar bas-relief](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Louvre-Lens_(bas-relief).JPG) where the photo is CC-BY-SA and the sculptor long dead.

Comment: I get the impression (based on you asking how to do this in Photoshop) that this "logo" project would best be performed by a professional illustrator with the skill to build a likeness of the image that is similar enough to be recognizable, yet different enough that you could trademark it. If you are indeed going to use this as a logo, then you are much better off doing it right than doing it cheap.

Answer (score 4):

You **redraw** it entirely.

You typically *can't* edit a photo of a sculpture (assuming you have the rights to use the image) in a fashion that is applicable to logotypes. You need to manually either use software or a pen and paper to draw the aspects of the sculpture in a way that would still indicate the overall image, yet be simplified enough to be usable as a logo.

There's no "magic" combination of software commands to take a photograph of a sculpture to a usable logotype. If there were, all logo designers would be out of work.

Answer (score 1):

Short of redrawing it entirely, maybe you could posterise it?

2 levels would be black & white, 3 has an intermediate grey, more gets eventually closer to full greyscale…

[image]

<sup>The more I look at this, the more I think it should be entitled "Mother gives son a good slap" ;-)</sup>

Comment: Oh, that last comment. Can't unsee!